# Laravel 5 installation on Centos 7 issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, centos7

I successfully installed the latest Laravel framework on my Centos 7 VHost.
After the composer command was done installing it, I created a new Laravel project. 
For that I went o **/var/www/** and created a folder there called "**great**" , then I changed directory to enter it, so **pwd** showed me

> /var/www/great/

Then I ran this command:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject
```

The last one, created (as expected) a new folder inside the "**great**" folder called "**myproject**"

According to the Laravel installation instructions, I changed my directory to be inside the myproject folder and when I run

```
php artisan -V
```

I get:

> Laravel Framework version 5.0.16

then I ran the command

```
php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.60 --port 80
```

with 192.168.1.60 being my vhost's IP address. So i expect to be able to see the Laravel page from my other computer (windows) when I access the ip in my browser, but it's not happening. All I get in my browser is:

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

At first I tried it without specifying the host or the port... same result. Then I discovered that I need to specify the host in order to be able to access the project from locations other than localhost. So I tried accessing it by going for http://192.168.1.60:8000 (because that is it's default port). Same result.

I can ping the IP, on Centos side I do not get any error when I run the artisan serve....
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to add your IP address in your config file..not sure but it could be the reason.

Comment: In which config file? I am new to Laravel.

Comment: Maybe there some issue with port on your server try to run "netstat -a | grep -i LISTEN" on your terminal.

Comment: I ran it... what should I look for in the result?

Comment: I solved it by re-installing the OS as Centos 6 and re-installing Laravel. It works now perfectly. I do not know what happened with the Centos 7 but I do not have that much time to waste tryting to solve it. Maybe later after some of the work is done and I have spare time to play with intricate installation stuff

Comment: It might have been that I should have done: `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 80`